# Cordova still wants to load plugins after remove

Tags: cordova, plugins, uninstallation, package.json

I am working on a PhoneGap / Cordova-Project and wanted to get rid of plugins I don't need. I uninstalled several plugins with CLI:

```
$ cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-file-transfer
```

Now, when I load the App in a preview, the uninstalled plugins seem to be loaded still, as they throw a net::ERR_ABORTED - exception:

```
GET http://192.168.178.67:3000/plugins/cordova-plugin-media-capture/www/CaptureAudioOptions.js net::ERR_ABORTED
    (anonymous) @   onsenui.min.js:2
    exports.injectScript    @   cordova.js:1534
    injectIfNecessary   @   cordova.js:1542
    handlePluginsObject @   cordova.js:1595
    (anonymous) @   cordova.js:1624
    (anonymous) @   cordova.js:1544
```

The config.xml references correctly only the installed plugins. Nevertheless I noticed that the /www/package.json does not include any of the plugins. There is a /www/package-lock.json which has no plugins either. Yet I found another package-lock.json in the root of the project.

I tried to use

```
$ cordova prepare
```

to rebuild the package.json, but that seems to do nothing. My guess is that I somehow ****ed-up the package.json file and cordova seems to be unable to restore it.

Is there a way to re-build the package.json?
Where should the package.json and the package-lock.json reside?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok for someone with the same Problem, after much research and help from a friend, I finally solved the Problem:

I deinstalled all platforms that were installed:

```
$ cordova platform remove browser
$ cordova platform remove android
```

Then I cleaned up the project:

```
$ cordova clean
```

...and reinstalled the platforms. Then fixed the package.json problem and the missing files errors.